# Vulkan SDK Version 1.1.85.0 linking on Kubuntu 18.10

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, vulkan

I'm currently working on a game engine with vulkan. 
I just wanted to try whether it compiles on linux, but I don't know how to link my Vulkan SDK libraries. I downloaded the "vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.85.0.tar.gz" from the LunarG homepage, but now I dont know what I should link under "target_link_libraries".

I tried to link the "libvulkan.so" from the lib folder, but it does not work.
Some help from you would be great, because I never worked with CMAKE on linux.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvulkan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Untitled.dir/build.make:669: ../output_linux    /Untitled] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/Untitled.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/Untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: Untitled] Error 2
```

Thanks for help,
Marlon

Answer (score 1):

The SDK's Linux Getting Started Guide found in your SDK tarball and at this [link](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.85.0/linux/getting_started.html) explains much of this.  In fact, there's even a section called "Using Vulkan in CMake Projects" that shows how to use the `FindVulkan` CMake module.  The SDK also contains numerous example programs, also built with CMake.